# How to add C# extension to create a new project in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a small problem , I am currently using visual studio with an installed C++ compiler . Now I wanna create a GUI in C# for a code I have I want to open a windows form application. But when I try to create a new project , obviously there is no option to create one because the .net is not installed . I haven't found some simple explanation of how to add the extension of C# to create a C# application in visual studio.
If someone knows how to do so , i'll  be very thankful !
thanks in advance !

Comment: You can do it through installer. Open installer, find Visual studio, go to modify and you can install .Net desktop development package

Answer (score 2):

If you've installed Visual Studio, you should have a program called "Visual Studio Installer" installed. From there you have the option to install, update and uninstall new packages.

Image for reference: https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fvisualstudio%2Finstall%2Fmedia%2Fvs-2019%2Fvs-installer-workloads.png%3Fview%3Dvs-2019&f=1&nofb=1